# Need Assistance Wiring a Duct Booster Fan

Tags: wiring, hvac, ducts

Morning, folks. And thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

We have an in-line duct fan in the attic. It assists in moving air from the central HVAC system into our addition. It is hooked up to a 24v/12v relay to control on/off and controlled by two 24v connections. The first comes form the furnace and the second comes form a thermostat in the addition. When the HVAC is active AND the thermostat in the addition is triggered, it completes the circuit and the fan is powered.

To the point, the fan finally failed and needs to be replaced. I'd like to replace the relay at the same time. The HVAC contractor I called out wants nearly $700 to do the job, with the fan costing around $350. I just don't have that kind of money right now, but we're cold!

Now, I can buy a fan similar to what was installed for between $80-$150. I can replicate the wiring as it was previously done. I'm fine with the duct work, and I'm fine wiring something to voltage. I can also replicate the wiring as it was done for the old fan. But I need to make sure I'm going about it the right way. So, I have a few questions if you're willing:

1. Should I just pay them the $700 and be done with it? Am I too far out of my depth? Am I likely to be bumping up against so many safety and code issues that I should just pay to have it done?
2. Many of the in-line duct fans I've seen plug directly into a 120v outlet. I was thinking I could just rig the relay to energize a 120v outlet and plug the fan into that. In this way, I can just plug a new fan in if/when needed. I know codes differ from location to location. But is controlling a 120v outlet with thermostats and a relay ever OK?
3. Let's say #2 is a no-go. I need to identify a proper relay. Can I use any old 24v to 120v relay to power the fan?
4. I'd love for all of this to be stuffed into a junction box, but it looks like any relay I see is mounted outside of the junction box. I assume this is to keep the low voltage and line voltage separate. So I take it that it's never OK to hide the relay inside a junction box?

I know enough to know that I'm probably out of my depth here. I just want someone else to confirm it before I spend half of next month's mortgage payment on a fan. Of course, "Don't pay those bloodscuckers, dude. This is super easy and I'm going to show you how" would be even better. Thanks in advance!

EDITED TO ADD IMAGES

[image: Relay]
[image: Fan1]
 [image: Fan2]

Editing to add "schematic" to the degree that you can call this a schematic. Hopefully it provides enough information.

[image: Amature Schematic]

Comment: If you are just swapping out the fan, why do all the rewiring?

Comment: Yes, if it ain't broke, why do you want to fix it?

Comment: 1. i wouldn't, this is DIY turf. 2. I see no electrical/safety problems with that, but you can use a UL-approved smart outlet of some sort if in doubt, or a dusk to dawn outlet control and a 24v lamp. 3. yes. 4. not bare relays, but there are some approved switches, like sonoff, that are double insulated.

Comment: Yehuda_NYC: Because I pulled the fan and the relay out without making a note of how it was wired in the first place, of course! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just pay them the $700 and be done with it?

Depends on ..

> Am I too far out of my depth?

Can you operate a screwdriver, watch you tube, turn off a circuit breaker .

> Am I likely to be bumping up against so many safety and code issues
>   that I should just pay to have it done?

Only the fan matters - UL Listed, GFCI Circuit if the location has high humidity like a shower (probably already is if that is the case)

> Many of the in-line duct fans I've seen plug directly into a 120v
>   outlet. I was thinking I could just rig the relay to energize a 120v
>   outlet and plug the fan into that. In this way, I can just plug a new
>   fan in if/when needed. I know codes differ from location to location.
>   But is controlling a 120v outlet with thermostats and a relay ever OK?

Why do this you don't need to! 
Your current fan is 120V or possibly but not likely 220v - just use the three wires on your current fan (Black , White , and Green/copper) which are probably wire nutted in a junction box by the fan motor and swap out with a new fan.

You can probably buy a new fan of the exact same type as yours online for $100.. Do an online search of the model number found on the motor faceplate.

> Let's say #2 is a no-go. I need to identify a proper relay. Can I use any old 24v to 120v relay to power the fan?

Your HVAC relay that is 24V - that is the solenoid side - not the load side - the load side is 120V or 220V and is what turns on your fan.

I'd love for all of this to be stuffed into a junction box, but it looks like any relay I see is mounted outside of the junction box. I assume this is to keep the low voltage and line voltage separate. So I take it that it's never OK to hide the relay inside a junction box?

> You misunderstand: the relay is inside the junction box with Low
>   voltage on the COIL side (which pulls in the contact side) and 120VAC or 220VAC on the Contact side.
>   This is perfectly fine and good that they did this.

Here is an electrical Diagram of what you probably have and should see..
[image: Fan with Relay]

Comment: thanks. First, yes, I'm comfortable with the electrical. It's the code I'm concerned about. But this is also HVAC, about which I know nothing and want to make sure that there aren't any special considerations.   The idea of using an outlet was just to address the fact that the cheaper fans have a standard plug on the end and are not hardwired.  Unfortunately, I did look up a direct replacement for the fan, and it's in excess of $350. That's why I'm looking to the cheaper DIY route.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JD_HART - take a picture of your motor faceplate and the fan itself .. post that here .. $350 is most likely an HVAC dealer price - sometimes you buy the motor and the other pieces you can re-use ..The faceplate will list Manufacturer, Model, Voltage, FLA etc..

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded images of the fan and relay to the original post. I was thinking about replacing them with a Fantech FG-8 for FG-8XL <http://www.fantech.net/products/fans--accessories/circular-duct-fans/fans-for-circular-ducts-with-ac-motors/fg/fg-8-centrifugal-inline-fan/> and this relay <https://customer.honeywell.com/en-US/pages/product.aspx?cat=HonECC+Catalog&pid=RC840T-120/U>  What are your thoguhts on that?

Comment: @JD_HART looking at your picture (hard to read the text), the Model of the motor looks like 4C445A - tell me if that is correct. If so this motor and blower assembly can be had for $125.00 (as it is NLA from grainger where it was listed $51.00)  a cross reference https://www.amazon.com/R7-RB445-Rotom-Replacement-Blower-Dayton/dp/B005RAHEG6 or here http://www.electricmotorwarehouse.com/r7-rb445-rotom-replacement-blower-549-cfm-115v/#sthash.oizTuUrG.dpbs for $110 Another issue you have is that motor is rusty, meaning Moisture. How is moisture getting into contact with motor or condensing on it.

Comment: That's correct, Ken. 4C445A. However, it has a rectangular opening that  required some sheet metal work. I plan on using something meant to connect to 8" insulated flex duct. I was thinking about a Fantech FG 8XL, FG 8, or FG225.  The rust could have come from a few places. The unit is in an attic over the garage and it's not climate controlled. It could be high humidity. I also found a shower fan exhaust venting to the attic not far from the fan (now fixed). The latter seems the more likely culprit. Lastly, what are your thoughts on the relay I selected? Does that look like a good option?

Comment: @JD_HART the honeywell site was down the other day and today the link does not work 'commerce error'. Does your current fan have a rectangular opening or a circular opening ? A pair of shear scissors is cheap ($5) . The relay has both a voltage and amperage rating for the contacts - the amperage should be 20% more than the maximum motor current. So for an 8 amp motor a 10 Amp relay is appropriate a 5 amp relay is NOT.
I think you are probably getting into more rework instead of just replacing - as the old system lasted a long time - why not simply have the same life cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Ken. The current fan (which is currently residing somewhere in the municipal dump, did have one circular and one rectangular opening. But the connection was to two circular ducts. The rectangular opening was kludged together with bad sheet metal work and and adapter. It will actually be easier to use a unit that is 8" circular on both sides. Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: So, ultimately, it looks like I am going to go with a Fantech FG-8XL and a Honeywell-Aube RC840T-120. Links are https://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-Aube-RC840T-120-120v-Relay-w-Built-In-24V-Transformer and https://www.supplyhouse.com/Fantech-FG8XL-FG-Series-Round-Inline-Exhaust-Fan-8-Duct-502-CFM. The fan says it pulls a max of 1.45 amps. I can't seem to find an amperage rating on the relay. Assuming that the links work for you this time, will this combo work?

Comment: @JD_HART I got the links and the ratings (except for the 120V side of the relay). Since they have a 240V 22A, the 120V is probably half that rating. The relay appears to be one that can power a thermostat you do not need to as yours should already be powered. The relay pic in your post has a Relay Control (2 blue wires? - 24V) and output Load Contact (250V 10AMP 2 red wires) = 4 wires total - matching my drawing, your linked one is different. While the linked relay can work it might be better just to opt in for a standard relay and connect as before. can you provide details on blue wire conns.

Comment: I'll need to check the wiring when I get home. Is the "blue" actually supposed to be blue? Because I don't recall seeing any blue wire. The relay that was in there can be found at http://www.radwell.com/en-US/Buy/RBM%20CONTROLS/RBM%20CONTROLS/129515-3180Z. Not sure if that helps determine what should go in there.  I'll look when I get home and post back as soon as I can. Ken, after this is all over, I'm going to have to buy you a drink. Thanks a ton for all of your help.

Comment: @JD_HART the relay in your picture - of your post shows Blue Wires. They are the low voltage side (24V) the Red wires are the high voltage (120VAC) side - I know this because of the wire gauge and if you peeled back the red wires from covering up the label on that relay in your post we would see them identified as such.

Comment: @JD_HART - yes looking at the link for your relay - exactly the blue wires on yours or the grey on the linked pictured (the label has BLU) for the coil and Red wires for the contact. Red wires supply 120VAC to the FAN - 120VAC Hot wire from power source (should be a Black or Red Wire of similar gauge / thickness) other Red wire to the Fan lead. The two blues (or grey) are the control coil and come from the controlling circuit i.e your thermostat circuit , one wire will be a common the other will be the actual control line - maybe white of similar gauge or smaller thickness than the blue.

Comment: @JD_HART if you take a picture or draw a diagram / with labels of your current wires that would hook to your fan / relay and post that  - perhaps we can assist you better.

Comment: I've updated the original post with an image of how I believe the fan was wired before I dismantled it. I should have noted how it was set up before I took it apart, but I didn't. The only thing I'm not sure about is how the two 24v components (the furnace in the main part of the house and the remote thermostat in the addition) completed the circuit on that side of the switch. Now, I don't know how to draw a proper wiring diagram, so I did the best I could. Hopefully this helps. And thanks again for sticking with me!

Comment: @JD_HART - the wiring hookup looks correct, the switch(you mean relay?) .Your other control side (coil side ) of the relay as long as you use the same two wires as previously it should work. Your drawing indicates the proper wiring connections. The thermostat is pretty old school (+- 6 degrees swing) hopefully yours is digital (with adj. swing). I have a LUX thermostat and set a 2 degree swing because generally a person can't detect 2 degrees but 3 or more they can much more economical as well, some Hwells are fixed at .5 , more electric $$ and forces the equipment to cycle $$ more often$.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. Yes, in my semi-informed parlance switch=relay. As for the thermostat, I used images of the items I actually plan to use or have wherever possible. That's the actual thermostat! At some point I'll replace the thermostat. I'm going to order the parts indicated and give this a shot. Thanks a ton, and I'll check back in once I've completed the install!